# How to assign a fixed device number to a camera?

Tags: udev, v4l

I need my usb video camera (A4Tech) to take `/dev/video0` and the capture card (analog converter) to take `/dev/video1` regardless of the order I connect them to PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it can be done; but you can create a persistent symlink based on a device attribute (for instance ID_MODEL).

Plug in your e.g. camera and run

```
udevadm info --export-db > file.txt
```

then look at file.txt to locate the camera (perhaps search for A4Tech?) and find the ID_MODEL attribute.

Then create a file called `/target/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-capture-device.rules` and put stuff like this in it:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="'YOUR_ID_MODEL'", SYMLINK+="a4tech-camera", ENV{GENERATED}="1"
```

Obviously, substitute YOUR_ID_MODEL with the value you found by looking at udevadm output.

When you plugin the camera, a symlink to the appropriate video* device will be created as `/dev/a4tech-camera`.

You can add a similar line to the same file for your capture card, assuming it shows in udevadm output and you can find an ID_MODEL or other attribute to identify it.

Comment: This works fine on my Ubuntu machine (after restart or several `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules`s). Though on target machine (buildroot-based linux on an embedded system) there is no udev. Devices are managed by devtmpfs. So, are udev rules applied to a system with no udev daemon?

Comment: Sorry, no; they are udev-specific. Perhaps devtmpfs has similar functionality, as it's very common. I'd google for devtmpfs symlink or something similar. I have no experience with devtmpfs :/ (though in my defense, this site is about ubuntu-specific stuff :) you could ask in unix.stackexchange.com for more help.